# Get the value from select form in EmberJS and ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new in Ember and I am creating an App with some models relationships.

These are my models

```
// models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  role: DS.belongsTo('role')
});

// models/role.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My new user route is

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      newUser: this.store.createRecord('user'),
      roles: this.store.findAll('role'),
    });
  }
});
```

The idea is get the roles and selecting in a select view in the form

This is my template for create a new User

```
<form {{ action "save" on="submit" }}>
  {{ input value=newApplicant.name class="form-control" }}
  <select name="role" class="form-control" value="role.value">
       {{#each model.roles as |role|}}
             <option value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option>
       {{/each}}
  </select>
```

Until this step all is OK, I have my select with the proper data, but I want to save I do not know how to get the role id from the form and insert to the user

This is my new controller

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

newUser: Ember.computed.alias('model.newUser'),
roles: null,
// roles: Ember.computed.alias('model.roles'),


actions: {
  save() {
    var role = this.get('role.value');
    console.log(role);
    //this.get('newUser').save().then((user) =>
    //  this.transitionToRoute('users', user.get('id'))
    //);
  },
});
```

I have done some experiments but nothing has working. When I click in Save send in the JSON request to the server a null value in role.

I have follow this tutorial http://thau.me/2014/11/ember-data-mastering-async-relationships-part-2/

But when I try to filter I got Null.

How can obtain the value from the select form? What is the best way to do this?

BTW, I am using Ember 2 and ember data 2

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for this might  help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to update a fews thing in order for that to work.

See [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/772aba53c1942fdb5b58?openFiles=application.controller.js%2Capplication.template.hbs) for a full reference.

On the template side, the select tag needs to send the value on the change event. I've removed the `value=""` and replaced it with a onchange event.

```
<select name="role" class="form-control" onchange={{action "updateValue" value="target.value"}}>
 {{#each model.roles as |role|}}
  <option value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option>
 {{/each}}
</select>
```

Then you need an action in your controller to deal with this, the `updateValue` action will receive the value from the select box and set it to the `role.value` property, which you can retrieve later on the `save` action:

```
actions:{
  updateValue: function(value) {
    this.set('role.value', value);
  },
  save() {
   var role = this.get('role.value');
   console.log(role); // Now this should work
  }
}
```

I don't think the `select` tag has a value property.

In essence the issue was that your `select` tag was not binding it's value anywhere. For a more powerful select component, I highly recommend [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com).

Comment: Its works! But I have to change my model to delete all relationships. Now my user model is

    // models/user.js
    export default DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      role: DS.belongsTo('role')
    });